# Adaptis Training - GPU hangs after few iterations

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, gpu, freeze, torch

I have a problem while training Adaptis (https://github.com/saic-vul/adaptis/tree/pytorch).
When i want to train it, the GPU (RTX 3080) just stop working.
While it is working the GPU needs 95% of the resources, but when it hang it do not need any resources.

I am using the pytorch branch of the git repo.

Does anyone have the same problem and can help me?

Computer:

CPU: Ryzen 9 5900

RAM: 32 GB

GPU: RTC 3080

[image]

Comment: Do system logs show messages of the sort "GPU ... has fallen off the bus"? If so, the most likely cause is insufficient power supply. As it stands, the observation points to a hardware or software configuration issue, not a programming issue, which makes it off-topic here.

Comment: Could be possible your process has gone to Sleeping or Zombie state. Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643476/whether-my-process-is-hung-or-running).

Comment: 1 from 5 PID are in running state and the other 4 went to sleeping state, how can i fix this problem?